# How do you keep track of deployment ids and builds

Tags: devops

Currently I am working in a project where we have 8 instances accross different geographies. We currently use bmc rlm (  https://docs.bmc.com/docs/ReleaseLifecycleMgt/50 ) for deployment automation.

- However to keep track of our deployment ids we are using excel.
  Starting from Dev environment , to QA environment ( each region has
  its own QA and schedule ) and ultimately move to Production.
- What I wanted to know was , is there any tool that you use to keep
  track of deployments ?
- We tried using sharepoint but it is kind of limiting in the features.
  We would ideally like a workflow to be created , whereby developers
  submit the request with the dev deployment id.
- Workflow goes to Release Approver for QA env. Once he/she approves , 
  QA testing team gets notified.

Please let us know if anybody else faced this kind of issue and used some tools for the same?

Answer (score 1):

We have recently started public preview of Reliza Hub https://relizahub.com which aims to solve this problem.

Some of the functionality you are asking (particularly approvals) is not there yet, but it's coming. Tracking functionality and mapping instance to releases is there already.

Currently I'm trying to add documentation as we go, so far Version Increment workflow is documented [here](https://worklifenotes.com/2020/02/27/automatic-version-increments-with-reliza-hub-2-strategies/). And functionality to send release data to Reliza Hub is documented in our [client github](https://github.com/relizaio/relizaGoClient).

Would be happy to provide support and discuss incomplete or missing features via our new reddit channel [r/Reliza](https://reddit.com/r/Reliza).